# Constraint constant is nil iOS 7 but not in iOS 8

Tags: ios7, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, iboutlet

I have 3 outlets that change constant variables in 3 views, and can't seem to understand why this happens.  NOTE:  THIS HAS NOTHING TO WITH THE INTERFACE (so no setneedlayout or layoutifneeded answers).  I get it.

```
// iOS 7
_fillerConstraint.constant = 200;
NSLog(@"_fillerConstraint: %f", _fillerConstraint.constant);
```

2015-02-15 08:55:14.54 Hurricane[44367:613] _fillerConstraint: 0.000000

```
// iOS 8
 _fillerConstraint.constant = 200;
NSLog(@"_fillerConstraint: %f", _fillerConstraint.constant);
```

2015-02-15 08:55:14.547 Hurricane[44367:613] _fillerConstraint: 200.000000

A method is called from viewwillappear to set these values and do some animation.  All is well in iOS 8 and works as expected. However in iOS7 the debugger is reporting the constraint is nil.  Anyone know what might cause this behavior?

Comment: Any chance that `_fillerConstraint` is nil for some reason in the first example?

Comment: @PhillipMills You are correct!  It's reporting nil in iOS 7.  I have set the properties to both weak and strong, and it's nil.  I am baffled as to why.

Comment: You're in an area I don't really know, but I wonder if there's been an OS change in when constraints are initialized.  If you moved your code to `viewDidAppear`, would the result be different?

Comment: @PhillipMills  No, it's still nil viewdidappear.  There has to be some symptom as to why it's nil in iOS 7.  I'm not sure how to debug it.

Comment: Do you use Auto Layout features available only in iOS 8? Like size classes or layout margins?

Comment: @MichałCiuba  Yes, I am using size classes in iOS 8.

Comment: Ok, am learning more about size classes not being compatible with ios7.  Perhaps that is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning the app and resetting the simulators.  It works fine.  The answer to issues like this is, Xcode 6 is full of bugs.

Comment: This worked (Xcode 6.3). Also disabling classes and void using it until the very last adjustments is highly advised to avoid this and other unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound dumb, but for future dummies my problem was that the constraint was with a view that is no longer in the view hierarchy(I removed it) so obviously the constraint was nil.